# Protecting tiles from damage caused by child

Tags: tile, protection

I have a one year old at home who takes great pleasure in pulling utensils from kitchen cabinets (which are just a little higher than him) and banging and dragging them on the floor. This has made impressions on the (brand new!) tiles and scratches which we aren't able to get rid off.

How can I protect my tiles from such damage ?

One thought was to lay chair mats (office) but they are of a weird shape and will need more than a few of them to cover a 6' by 10'rectangular tiled kitchen space.

I do not want to curtail his curiosity. Child safety locks are useless as he can simply pull the drawer with his force - bringing down the child safety lock. Now we have resigned to not keeping glassware in the cabinet.

Comment: You can buy industrial rubber matting in large sheets or as interlocking tiles. Side note: Unbounded facilitation of your child's curiosity might be somewhat incompatible with preserving your home and contents in a presentable state. ;-)

Comment: +1000 related to the side note. Setting and enforcing limits is probably more important to the learning process than unbridled curiosity.

Comment: I agree. Creating and enforcing boundaries is at least as important as entertaining curiosity. Children that believe they can do anything with no consequences are a danger to themselves and to others. Give the child a container of safe, undamaging toys they can play with and enforce the idea that there are places they cannot go without being punished.

Comment: You have a behavioral problem, not a home-design problem.  I'm a bit surprised that a child that young can overcome safety locks (perhaps you chose a crummy model?), but he's certainly old enough to train NOT to do stuff like this.  Yes, it takes time and patience, but what you're proposing is to reward his behavior!

Comment: This should be migrated to http://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [red rosin paper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010SJYSVO)

[image]

[Ram Board](http://www.ramboard.com/products/ram-board.html)

[image]

Or some other similar product.  These products are used by builders and contractors, to protect flooring during construction.  They can be trimmed easily to fit any size and shape floor, are fairly cheap, and easily removable.

Comment: I used something like http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/44881100/ . Better suited for underneath of some chair, but, depending on dimensions, it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Child proof the drawer. It will protect the floor and the child. There are various baby proofing solutions besides the latches shown in the pictures below. Some people claim that they break, but I didn't have that problem. So there may be a brand difference (regarding the latches).

[image]